Minecraft (Switch): Why isn't the minus button bringing up the chat window?
We're trying to get the Command Block in Minecraft for Nintendo Switch.

Command Block
The block isn't present in the inventory, but apparently it needs to be added to the inventory through the chat window.
Okay, that's fine - except that our chat window is hidden no matter what. The minus button is unresponsive.

The mode is Creative
In Settings the Command Block is enabled
Accessibility > Enable Open Chat Message is ON

Why isn't the minus button bringing up the chat window? What else do we need to do?
(And why is the ability to use a certain block bound to the chat feature anyway?)
Next I'm going to investigate the Switch's parental controls to see if maybe something there is blocking chat...

Does the button work anywhere else on the Switch?
